# Makefile: What does $(VARIABLE:/text=) mean?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Can someone explain to me what the following variable declaration (for `MY_DIR`) means please?

```
MY_CLOUD = $(shell .......)
MY_DIR ?= $(MY_CLOUD:/cloud=)
```

Specifically after the `?=`, which I understand to mean "set `MY_DIR` if it does not already hold a value".

I cannot seem to find the documentation on this, but I assumed it to mean "set to the value of `MY_CLOUD` if it not empty, otherwise set to `/cloud`", but this doesn't seem to ring true in practice.  I don't get the `=`.

Comment: See Barry's answer.  But to reinforce his comment, the `?=` and the `:...` format in the variable are completely different things.  They don't interact with each other and you can use either one with or without the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MY_DIR ?= $(MY_CLOUD:/cloud=)
```

There are two parts here:

- `$(MY_CLOUD:/cloud=)` is a [substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs). This is taking the variable `$(MY_CLOUD)` and replacing `/cloud` with nothing.
- `MY_DIR ?= expr` is a [conditional assignment](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Assignment). It is defined as:

  ```
  ifeq ($(origin MY_DIR), undefined)
    MY_DIR = expr
  endif
  ```

  but obviously much shorter.

Put together, if `MY_DIR` wasn't already defined, this assigns it to the value of `MY_CLOUD` after removing all instances of `/cloud`

Answer (score 2):

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html:

> If you’d like a variable to be set to a value only if it’s not already set, then you can use the shorthand operator ‘?=’ instead of ‘=’.